# Load list from api for dropdown only when tapped

Tags: flutter, dart

I want a situation whereby when I tap a flutter dropdown, it pulls an updated list from api and render. I have tried using gestureDetector. So on tap it loads the list. But I don't know how to display the loaded list

In order words, how do I make flutter dopdownButtom item a future

Comment: What you have achieved so far?

Comment: @Muhammad Noman Literally I want when I tap on the dropdown, I would check if my list is emppty/updated, if it is i'll run a future task to grap the updated list and display the list. So far for the first part, I achieved it by wrapping my dropdownbutton in a gesturedetector. and then in on tap I called the api to grab my list. The only thing is that I never got the dropdown to render my list

Comment: @terminator can you add some code